# Visual studio online query items without tags

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

When are working with various Work Item types (user stories,Tasks, etc) we assign tags to reference the area of work. This makes it easy to filter the Backlogs items view to find any related stories.

I would like to build a query to identify Work Items where the tags have not yet been assigned.

I know this can be achieved using excel and filtering, however I specifically would like to do this using the queries. Is this possible??

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This could be unworkable so I'm not posting it as an answer just yet, but you could build a query with multiple "Tags Does Not Contain" clauses and "AND" them together with each clause picking a tag from the list. I'd probably do this as a Linqpad query against the API though.

Comment: I did think to do a list but as I the team uses >100 tags maintaining a list would be more effect than it I could just get the query to look for "Tags = none"

Comment: I guess it is excel/API, or just query for all relevant work items, then sort them by tags, those without will go to the top/bottom together.

Comment: @DaveShaw you can't sort by tags to my knowledge

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I have to say that it is not possible to create work item query to show work items which don't contain tags. As you see that the **Operator** for **Tags** is **Contains** or **Does Not Contain**, it is not possible to use these two operators to filter out these non-tagged work items.

Secondly, as you have more than 100 tags, it is not an effective way to use "Does Not Contain" operator to exclude all tagged work items.

So,

How about you adding a 'Null' tag to all non-tagged work items to specify that these work items don't have any tags? With this approach, you can create a work item query with Tags Contains Null to list these non-tagged work items.

If you don't want to take this approach, you need to work with excel just as you mentioned above, or take Dave's advice to work with API.

Comment: The excel solution is probably the best; Adding a Null tag is somewhat unworkable.. This means every time a work item is created, someone needs to add that Null tag.  It'd be easy to add a Null tag to everything not tagged if I had a query that showed me everything not tagged..  Circular dependencies